# PDO::prepare not properly escaping input from iPhone

Tags: php, mobile, pdo

I am inserting data into a database using PDO::prepare, and double quotes (example "pickled vegetables" are properly added to database when form is accessed from a computer. However, when input is from iPhone Safari, the insert is cut off right before the quotes and not implemented.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$location = $_POST['location'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$review = $_POST['review'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

//Create our INSERT SQL query.
if($_POST['location']) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO reviews (location, item, review, type) VALUES 
(:location, :item, :review, :type)";

//Prepare our statement.
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//Bind our values to our parameters (we called them :make and :model).
$statement->bindValue(':location', $location);
$statement->bindValue(':item', $item);
$statement->bindValue(':review', $review);
$statement->bindValue(':type', $type);


//Execute the statement and insert our values.
$statement->execute();

}

?>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's the actual error you are receiving?

Comment: Not receiving any error. When I try to upload a string with either quotes, or a dash (iPhone automatically converts double hyphen to a dash), the insert gets cut off at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: iOS 11 has a "smart punctuation" feature that converts quotes to curly quotes, double hyphens to dashes, etc. Apparently, the PDO::prepare statement has not yet accounted for these smart characters, and they must be manually isolated and replaced.